# Xcode LLDB's "po" command doesn't print anything

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

## Problem

- Nothing is displayed in the Variable View in the Xcode debug area, and the "po" command of LLDB does not print anything.

[image]

- Nothing is output from the simulator and the following error occurs from the real device.

[image]

## Environment

- macOS 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.3

## Reason

- ???

## Attempts

- remove DerivedData directory
- clean build folder
- restart Xcode app
- reboot the mac
- Change the console output setting to something other than "Target Output" (As you can see in the images, it was always "All Output".)
- Scheme setting check

  - Run → Info → Launch → check on the  (it checked on from the begining)
  - Run → Arguments → Invironment Variables → remove `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` (It wasn't exist from the beginning)
- Project → Build Settings → Swift Compiler — Custom Flags → Other Swift Flags → `-D DEBUG` (I try this way but it still doesn't work.)
- Try this with a different project → works fine

Comment: Check your build configuration, Release builds can have no access to variables memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but my build configuration is Debug.